# GetSQLValueString alternative to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to update to mysqli, i've almost updated the whole site but i'm facing a problem with GetSQLValueString. How can I change this to be compatible with mysqli or if necessary delete/change .

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", 
$theNotDefinedValue = "") 
    {
        if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
        }

        $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?
            mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

        switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "long":
            case "int":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "double":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "date":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "defined":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                break;
        }
        return $theValue;
    }
}

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['stid'])) {
    $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['stid'];
}
mysqli_select_db( $SIS,$database_SIS);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM payments WHERE stid = %s", 
GetSQLValueString($colname_Recordset1, "int"));
$Recordset1 = mysqli_query($SIS, $query_Recordset1) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysqli_num_rows($Recordset1);

?>
```

Comment: Why not use prepared statements with parameterized queries?

Comment: Not only your question is too broad for asking a refactor, it's also unclear as to what's the problem.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example because i am not familiar with prepared statements with parameterized queries. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The biggest problem with `GetSQLValueString` is that it exists. mysqli has built-in mechanisms for doing what you do with `sprintf()`. [This part of the docks](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) might be a good place to start reading.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change all **mysql_** to **mysqli_** and add the connection to the database as first parameter. In my case the connection to the database is **$conn_vote**. Be aware that I added $conn_vote as function's parameter :

```
function GetSQLValueString($conn_vote, $theValue, $theType,   $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")   
    {  
      $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) :   $theValue;  

      $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ?   mysqli_real_escape_string($conn_vote, $theValue) :  
mysqli_escape_string($conn_vote, $theValue);

      switch ($theType) {  
        case "text":  
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";  
          break;      
        case "long":  
        case "int":  
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";    
          break;    
        case "double":    
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";  
          break;  
        case "date":  
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
          break;  
        case "defined":  
          $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue :
$theNotDefinedValue;
break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the same and I found more appropriate to just get rid of this function and use `mysqli_real_escape_string` you can pass the data like this:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], md5($password))
```